# AllowEncodedSlashes Issue

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config, apache2.2

I am currently having issues with encoded slashes on my Apache server. The url structure is as follows:

```
www.site.com/url/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anotherurl.com/format/xml
```

I am then getting a 404 error from Apache (my application should handle all errors.)

Apparently the `AllowEncodedSlashes On` directive should help me in this spot, but it doesn't seem to be making any impact whatsoever. I've placed it in the httpd.conf like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs
ServerName site.com

AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restarted Apache with the `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` command.

I've been trying to solve this issue for days now. I've some people saying that the AllowEncodedSlashes directive works, and some people saying that it's buggy and should be depreciated. I'm wondering if there's an issue with AllowEncodedSlashes and clean URL's working together?

Anyway, all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but my guess would be  that `AllowEncodedSlashes` indeed doesn't work if it encounters proper slashes in the URL as well.

Comment: Hi Pekka! I don't think that's true. I've been looking for a solution and have come across a few other people who have managed to achieve what I'm attempting. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with Apache: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256

Answer (score 0):

You can use encode and decode URL for this type problem.

```
  var uri = "https://w3schools.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anotherurl.com/format/xml";
  var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
  var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);


After encode-
Encoded URI: https%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.anotherurl.com%2Fformat%2Fxml

After Decode-
Decoded URI: https://w3schools.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anotherurl.com/format/xml
```